# How to compute $BC$ in this triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Given the lengths of $AF$, $AE$, $AD$, $AC$, How can I calculate $BC$?

I tried to calculate $FD = \sqrt{AF^2 - AD^2}$,

$DE = \sqrt{AE^2 - AD^2}$,

$FE = DE + FD$,

$FC = AC - AF$.

But I don't know what I can do with all these lengths to compute $BC$. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha= \angle_{FAD}$, $\beta= \angle_{EAD}$. 
Then you are given $\cos\alpha= AD/AF$, and similarly $\cos\beta$. 
You can now compute $\cos (\alpha+\beta)$. 
As $\alpha+\beta = \angle_{CAB}$, you have the hypothenuse $AB$ of the right triangle $ABC$. 
You can finish the calculation now.

Comment: $D$ isn't on an angle bisector in general.

Comment: Yes, I realized it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Trigonometry is the way to go.

We know everything about triangles $ADF$ and $ADE$. That means we know $\angle FAD$ and $\angle DAE$. From that, we know their sum, $\angle FAE=\angle CAB$. That's enough to figure out everything we need about the big triangle.

Comment: Should I use similarity to figure out $AB$?

Comment: No, because the big triangle isn't similar to anything else in the picture. Use trigonometry; there will be an angle-sum formula in there.

Comment: No @Mohamed because it is not said that some of triangles are similar.